# Distinguishing Between Negation and Subtraction in ANTLR Expression Grammar

Tags: antlr3, antlr4

The following grammar is failing to make the distinction between negation and subtraction operations. It ignores the negation operation completely.

I assume this is happening because there is an abiguity... `negAtom` is very similar to `OPERATOR multOp`. How would i rewrite my grammar to accomodate both negation and subtraction while maintaining operator precedence with multiplication and division?

```
grammar Expr.g4

op: 
    multOp (OPERATOR multOp)*;

multOp: 
    negAtom (MULT_OPERATOR multOp)*; 

negAtom:
    NEG? atom;

atom:
    group | INT;

group:
    L op R;

L   : '(';
R   : ')';
NEG : '-';
ADD : '+';
MLT : '*';
DIV : '/';

OPERATOR : (NEG|ADD);
MULT_OPERATOR : (MLT|DIV);

INT : '0'..'9'+;
```

Example Parse Tree with input "-1":

[image: Parse tree with input "-1"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OPERATOR` will never match, since either `NEG` or `ADD` match first. 
In short: the first lexer rule that can match will match.

You should make lexer rules like `OPERATOR` a parser rule like `operator`.

This problem has been solved many times. Have a look at existing grammars.

For Antlr4 grammar have a look here: [list of antlr4 grammars at github](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4)